# _ctypes ImportError DLL load failed %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, add-on, error

OS : Windows 10 64 bits
Blender 2.83 64 bits => I haven't found a 32 bits version.
Python 3.7.7 32 bits environment within miniconda.
numpy 1.16.4

I got this error message when I try to load an add-on to Blender 2.83 with a 32 bits system python 3.7 environment.

Here is the stack trace :

```
(tybl32) C:\>"%PYTHONHOME%/python.exe" "C:\tympan_blender\tyblender\blty" "start"
creating C:\Users\d19749\AppData\Local\blender-tympan\2.83\scripts\addons
copying C:\tympan_blender\tyblender\blender\addon -> C:\Users\d19749\AppData\Local\blender-tympan\2.83\scripts\addons\blty
copying C:\tympan_blender\tyblender\blender\config\startup.blend to C:\Users\d19749\AppData\Local\blender-tympan\2.83\config\startup.blend
starting subprocess with command: blender --python-use-system-env --addons blty
found bundled python: C:\tympan_blender\blender-2.83.0\2.83\python
Exception in module register(): C:\Users\d19749\AppData\Local\blender-tympan\2.83\scripts\addons\blty\__init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tympan_blender\blender-2.83.0\2.83\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 382, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "C:\Users\d19749\AppData\Local\blender-tympan\2.83\scripts\addons\blty\__init__.py", line 23, in register
    from . import collectionwrapper
  File "C:\Users\d19749\AppData\Local\blender-tympan\2.83\scripts\addons\blty\collectionwrapper.py", line 4, in <module>
    from blty.element_types import (
  File "C:\Users\d19749\AppData\Local\blender-tympan\2.83\scripts\addons\blty\element_types.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import tympan_utils as tu
  File "C:\Users\d19749\AppData\Local\blender-tympan\2.83\scripts\addons\blty\tympan_utils.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\outils\miniconda3_64\envs\tybl32\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\outils\miniconda3_64\envs\tybl32\Lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 33, in <module>
    with RTLD_for_MKL():
  File "C:\outils\miniconda3_64\envs\tybl32\Lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 18, in __enter__
    import ctypes
  File "C:\outils\miniconda3_64\envs\tybl32\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 nÔÇÖest pas une application Win32 valide.
Saved session recovery to 'C:\Users\d19749\AppData\Local\Temp\quit.blend'

Blender quit
```

Blender is launch within a python script with this command :

```
cmd=['blender', '--python-use-system-env', '--addons', 'blty']
p = subprocess.run(cmd, env=env)
```

The env variable hold the system environment variables plus those notables ones :

```
set PYTHONHOME=C:\outils\miniconda3_64\envs\tybl32
set BLENDER_DIR=C:\tympan_blender\blender-2.83.0
set PYTHONPATH=%TYMPAN_INSTALL_DIR%\cython;%PYTHONHOME%\Lib;%PYTHONHOME%\Lib\site-packages;%PYTHONHOME%\DLLs;%PYTHONPATH%
set PATH=%BLENDER_DIR%;%PYTHONHOME%;%PATH%
```

What I unsuccessfully tried :

1. Miniconda 32 bits
2. Miniconda 64 bits with 32 bits Python 3.7 environment,
3. Downgrade numpy to 1.16.2
4. Rename blender python folder to python.old
   What I'd like to try :
   Using Blender 2.83 32 bits => Is there a way to get an official 32 Blender 2.83 version ?

Could it be an incompatibility between Blender 2.83 64 bits and addon relying on 32 bits system Python environement using numpy ?

Thank you for your attention and feedbacks.

Comment: I think 2.80 is the last version that comes with a 32 bit distribution. I wouldn't count on a 64 bit version running smoothly on a 32 bit system. You can get 2.80 32 bit here - https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.80/

Comment: Thank you for the advice @ChristopherBennett. Using a 64 bits Python environment solved the problem.